# Configure Zap Attack as a system wide proxy

Tags: configuration, proxy, settings, http-proxy, zap

I need a simple way to intercept all HTTP requests from client Linux machine (Mint, Ubuntu, OpenSuse). I am using ZAP Attack Proxy. Configuring web browsers and client applications individually to use ZAP Attack as a proxy is not an option for me. Preferably it must capture all requests in a Fiddler-like manner, with no or minimum configuration.

How do I configure ZAP attack as a system-wide proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Cant you set ZAP as a proxy in the global network settings?
That works for me on Fedora, I'm afraid I dont have a Mint/Ubuntu/OpenSuse system to try out, but this post implies its the same on Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/664777/systemwide-proxy-settings-in-ubuntu