# How to integrate ZAP with JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, continuous-integration, zap

can you all please give me idea on how to integrate ZAP tool with JMeter for security concerns and I need it to involve with daily CI builds??

And if this is wrong stack to ask this question, please direct me to one.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I recorded all the JMeter scripts. When I run JMeter, I need ZAP also to apply its security testings for all JMeter API calls. I need JMeter and ZAP to run in sequence for every API.

Comment: So you need to proxy JMeter requests via Zap?

Comment: You have to be more specific. You can use ZAP in many ways. So you should outline how it's used, what your goal is, and what you tried so far.

Comment: @Omer: Yes... i need to proxy JMeter requests via Zap.

Comment: Well, googling "JMeter proxy" give me [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669947/how-to-set-proxy-for-jmeter-from-behind-another-proxy) - isn't that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

JMeter can be configure as a [proxy](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jmeter-to-record-test-scenarios) to save all [ZAP](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpStartStart) requests and then you can re send same OWASP test on same or environment after fix or change.

> you can also configure ZAP to connect through another proxy - this is often necessary in a corporate environment.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I ve added my exact requirements in edit. Please take a look and do the needful.

Comment: You can add Zap as a proxy on server JMeter is doing the load test, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660859/configure-zap-attack-as-a-system-wide-proxy

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to configure JMeter to send all requests through [ZAP Intercepting Proxy](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpStartProxies#configuring-proxies). By default ZAP is running on the same host using port `8080` so you either need to run JMeter like:

```
jmeter -H localhost -P 8000 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Alternatively you can define the same settings via [Java Networking Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) like:

```
jmeter -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

And finally you can add the next lines to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
http.proxyHost=localhost
http.proxyPort=8080
https.proxyHost=localhost
https.proxyPort=8080
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up.

More information:

- [Using JMeter behind a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)